# How to fix thousands of overlapping xlabels in pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, xticks

Using a Dataframe to create a plot for stock price and the x-axis is showing everydays close price over the span of the 10 year data

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("USO.csv")
df = df[['Date', 'Close']]
df = df.set_index('Date')

plt.plot(df.index, df['Close'], color='forestgreen')`
```

Output
[image]
I would like something like this
[image]

Comment: please provide a reproducible input

Comment: Please also see the Matplotlib docs; this is the number one entry in the Troubleshooting page: (https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq/howto_faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order)